# Is there an easy way to define a step as being both a Given and a When

Tags: python, python-behave

I am building a Py Behave test framework and have a number of scenarios where what was previously a When step becomes a Given

E.G in one scenario

```
Given a user has is on the logon page 
When they login with credentials <user>
Then the user logs in
```

But in other scenarios

```
Given a user is on the logon page
And they login with credentials <user>
```

In my steps this would appear as

```
 @given('they login with credentials {user}')
 def step_impl(context):
    Do login code

 @when('they login with credentials {user}')
 def step_impl(context):
    Do login code
```

Is there a way to save having to write all these steps out twice, but be able to define Whens as Givens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use @step decorator provided in behave

Scenario one

```
Given a user has is on the logon page 
When they login with credentials <user>
Then the user logs in
```

Scenario two

```
Given a user is on the logon page
And they login with credentials <user>
```

Solution:

```
@step('they login with credentials {user}')
 def step_impl(context):
    Do login code
```

reference: https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/550

Comment: this would still mean I am writing repeated code in my steps file. the other way I was going to approach it, before the answer given above I was to call the step in another step.

Comment: No, you don't have to write the steps again, Just write one function with @step decorator which will do login part and you can use it with given, when and then

Comment: thank you I misunderstood the description there, that is another great way of handling this, and in my case is much easier to implement then the above.

Answer (score -1):

@given('they login with credentials {user}')
@when('they login with credentials {user}')
def step_impl(context):
Do login code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).